# How to optimize this simple function in scala

Tags: string, scala

I wrote a simple function, to replace all the `b` char of a string to `*`, and if it ends with `c`, then replace the ending `c` to `#`.

So I write the code as:

```
object Main {
    def fix(text: String) = {
        val s = text.replace("b", "*")
        if (s.endsWith("c")) {
            s.stripSuffix("c") + ("#")
        } else s
    }
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        println(fix("abbbbccc")) // -> a***cc#
    }
}
```

I think this code is not very good, not in scala-way. Since I'm new to scala, I don't know how to optimize it into a single line, or just a chain?

For example:

```
def fix(text: String) = {
    text.replace("b", "*") op { t =>
        if (t.endsWith("c")) {
            t.stripSuffix("c") + ("#")
        } else t
    }
}
```

This is a chain I expected. Note the method `op`, I hope there is such a method, like `map`. That we don't have to define a variale here.

Or there is some other API in scala, can make this method just one line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's better to use [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) in such cases:

```
def fix(s: String) = s.replace('b', '*').replaceFirst("c$", "#")
```

If you need an one-line transformation chain:

```
def fix(s: String) =
 Some(s.replace('b', '*')).map(s => if(s.endsWith "c") s.init + "#" else s).get
```

or

```
def fix(s: String) =
 Some(s).filter(_ endsWith "c").map(_.init + '#').getOrElse(s).replace('b', '*')
```

(you can also use "match", but it takes more than one line)

Comment: You posted this a just while I was typing the same. :-) Sometimes, solutions can be as simple as that.

Comment: thanks for your nice answer. And I want to know badly, is there is a method like `op` in my question?

Comment: Nice solution. Interesting to note that its really just straight java. Scala doesnt really add anything here

Answer (score 1):

As you really hope to see your "op" operator:

```
text.replace("b", "*") match {
    case t if (t.endsWith("c")) => t.stripSuffix("c") + ("#")
    case t => t
}
```

Comment: The `match` is what I want. I don't need to define another variable

Answer (score 1):

If you like regular expressions, you can do:

```
def fix(text: String) = {
  val EndsWithc = """(.*)c$""".r
  text.replace('b', '*') match { case EndsWithc(s) => s + "#" ; case t => t }
}
```